# Solving an equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a problem which consists on solving this equation : 
$$\int_{c}^{3}6(x-2)(3-x)dx=\frac{1}{20}$$
I know that this is equivalent to solve : 
$$300(3^2-c^2)-40(3^3-c^3)-720(3-c)-1=0$$
But, it is impossible for me to find a way to solve this equation...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$
 40c^3 - 300c^2 + 320c - 541=0,
$$
and it has exactly one real root, namely 
$$
c \approx 6.598209692080347760585823829853809067318\dots
$$

By the rational root test, this root is not rational.